# Изменение свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

Почему когда в javascript объекту меняю свойство (например, маленькому div в матрице div'ов), он выводится не в своей очереди?

Вот код:

```
//
// Создание матрицы.
//

function createMatrix() {
    var matrix = document.getElementById('matrix');
    var n = 20 * 20;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'cell';
        matrix.appendChild(div);
    }
    r = (randomcell(0, 399));
    alert(r);
    matrix.children[r].className = 'black';
}
```

Здесь я рисую матрицу из 400 маленьких дивов, после генерирую случайное число, и пытаюсь сделать один из квадратиков чёрным. Вследствие самый первый квадратик (то-бишь в самом верхнем левом углу) всегда чёрный, а последний квадратик (то-бишь в самом нижнем правом углу) убирается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? Почему так происходит?

**Дополнено.**

CSS файл:

```
#score
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

#matrix
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;    
}

#matrix .cell
{
    float: left;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;   
}

#matrix .black
{
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, глюк в стилях. Попробуйте последнее заменить на

```
matrix.children[r].className = 'cell black';
```

Попробуйте добавлять к элементам ID

```
div.setAttribute('id', 'div_'+i);
div.className = 'cell';
matrix.appendChild(div);
```

и вызывать потом через document.getElementById(); (чем-то мне не нравится массив children)